# Insert values 2 ways- 0 rows inserted

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to add 7 rows in 2 different ways. In both the result is 0 rows inserted.

```sql
create table bank
(
  MoveNo INT ,
  Valdate DATE not null,
  Amount NUMBER(9,2),
  Essence varchar2(30)
);

**//First way**
INSERT ALL
  INTO bank (MoveNo, Valdate, Amount, Essence) VALUES (1,'2001/01/01',500,'opening balance')
  INTO bank (MoveNo, Valdate, Amount, Essence) VALUES (2,'2001/01/10',3500,'salary')
  INTO bank (MoveNo, Valdate, Amount, Essence) VALUES (3,'2001/01/10',-460,'cheque 055786')
  INTO bank (MoveNo, Valdate, Amount, Essence) VALUES (4,'2001/01/12',1100,'deposit')
  INTO bank (MoveNo, Valdate, Amount, Essence) VALUES (5,'2001/01/14',-5.50,'account management')
  INTO bank (MoveNo, Valdate, Amount, Essence) VALUES (6,'2001/01/17',-300,'cheque 055787')
  INTO bank (MoveNo, Valdate, Amount, Essence) VALUES (7,'2001/01/19',-867,'credit card')
SELECT 7 FROM BANK;

**//Second way**
INSERT INTO bank (MoveNo, Valdate, Amount, Essence)
          select 1,'2001/01/01',500,'opening balance' from dual
union all select 2,'2001/01/10',3500,'salary' from dual
union all select 3,'2001/01/10',-460,'cheque 055786' from dual,
union all select 4,'2001/01/12',1100,'deposit' from dual,
union all select 5,'2001/01/14',-5.50,'account management' from dual,
union all select 6,'2001/01/17',-300,'cheque 055787' from dual,
union all select 7,'2001/01/19',-867,'credit card' from dual,
SELECT * FROM bank;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both statements, `'2001/01/01'` is not a `DATE` it is a string literal. Although Oracle will try to be helpful and implicitly apply the `TO_DATE` function to the string to convert the string to a date, it does not know the format of the date so it will use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. You are likely to get an error as the default `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is not likely to match `YYYY/MM/DD`. Instead, you should use a `DATE` literal or use `TO_DATE('2001/01/01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')`.

The `BANK` table has zero rows initially, so when you use `INSERT ALL ... SELECT 7 FROM BANK` the final `SELECT` will match zero rows and nothing will be inserted. Instead, you want to `SELECT ... FROM DUAL` which would give you a single row and correspondingly perform each of the `INSERT`s once:

```sql
INSERT ALL
  INTO bank (MoveNo, Valdate, Amount, Essence) VALUES (1, DATE '2001-01-01',  500,    'opening balance')
  INTO bank (MoveNo, Valdate, Amount, Essence) VALUES (2, DATE '2001-01-10', 3500,    'salary')
  INTO bank (MoveNo, Valdate, Amount, Essence) VALUES (3, DATE '2001-01-10', -460,    'cheque 055786')
  INTO bank (MoveNo, Valdate, Amount, Essence) VALUES (4, DATE '2001-01-12', 1100,    'deposit')
  INTO bank (MoveNo, Valdate, Amount, Essence) VALUES (5, DATE '2001-01-14',   -5.50, 'account management')
  INTO bank (MoveNo, Valdate, Amount, Essence) VALUES (6, DATE '2001-01-17', -300,    'cheque 055787')
  INTO bank (MoveNo, Valdate, Amount, Essence) VALUES (7, DATE '2001-01-19', -867,    'credit card')
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

For your second query, you have commas between the statements and are missing the final `;` statement terminator:

```sql
INSERT INTO bank (MoveNo, Valdate, Amount, Essence)
          select 1, DATE '2001-01-01',  500,    'opening balance'   from dual
union all select 2, DATE '2001-01-10', 3500,    'salary'            from dual
union all select 3, DATE '2001-01-10', -460,    'cheque 055786'     from dual
union all select 4, DATE '2001-01-12', 1100,    'deposit'           from dual
union all select 5, DATE '2001-01-14',   -5.50, 'account managment' from dual
union all select 6, DATE '2001-01-17', -300,    'cheque 055787'     from dual
union all select 7, DATE '2001-01-19', -867,    'credit card'       from dual;
```

Then you can do:

```sql
SELECT * FROM BANK;
```

As a separate statement and it will show 14 rows (7 from the `INSERT ALL` statement and 7 from the `INSERT .. SELECT` statement).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=02a63ea99b99dc2dbbe3d3c45edb65f7)*

Comment: Why need spaces? By what did you choose them? Thanks (:

Comment: @linorkhbur The added spaces are optional; however formatting your code neatly makes it more readable and easier to comprehend and debug. I choose to format my code neatly, you do not have to but I would suggest that you consider why it may be beneficial to do so.

Comment: I understand thought it MUST be format. Another question how SELECT 1 FROM DUAL; working? thank you.

Comment: In Oracle, the `DUAL` table always exists and always has exactly 1 row and you are just selecting literal values to insert into the appropriate columns of the destination table. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=90ec580334d4b51a7b13037919faaec3)